# About uniform continuity.

Tags: real-analysis, cauchy-sequences, uniform-continuity

$D\subset \mathbb{R}$ and $f:D \to \mathbb{R} $

**(1)** For every pair of sequences $\{u_n\},\{v_n\}$ in $D$ satisfying $\lim|u_{n}-v_{n}|=0 $,$\lim|f(u_n)-f(v_n)|=0$ holds.
$\implies $ $f$ is uniformly continuous.

**(2)** if $\{x_n\}$ is Cauchy in $D$ ,then $\{f(x_n)\}$ is a Cauchy sequence in $\mathbb{R}$.
$\implies $ $f$ is uniformly continuous.

I know inverse implications of these are true.
But, are these implications true ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Every* continuous map from $\Bbb R$ into $\Bbb R$ maps Cauchy sequences into Cauchy sequences. Since there are continuous map from $\Bbb R$ into $\Bbb R$ which are not uniformly continuous…

On the other hand, if $f\colon D\longrightarrow\Bbb R$ is *not* uniformly continuous, then there is some $\varepsilon>0$ such that, for each $\delta>0$, there are numbers $x,y\in D$ such that $|x-y|<\delta$ and $\bigl|f(x)-f(y)\bigr|\geqslant\varepsilon$. So, for each $N\in\Bbb N$, take $x_n,y_n\in D$ such that $|x_n-y_n|<\frac1n$ and that $\bigl|f(x_n)-f(y_n)\bigr|\geqslant\varepsilon$. Then $\lim_{n\to\infty}|x_n-y_n|=0$, but you *don't* have $\lim_{n\to\infty}\bigl|f(x_n)-f(y_n)\bigr|=0$.

Comment: What about the first one?

Comment: Done! Anything more?

Comment: This is about sequential definition of uniform continuity, but I didn't find it in my text book, can you please give it?

Comment: Or is it what given in option (1) in the question?

Comment: And can you give a suitable example for contradicting (2)?

Comment: What is the “sequential definition of uniform continuity”? And a suitable example contradicting (**2**) is **any** continuous but not uniformly continuous function from $\Bbb R$ into $\Bbb R$, such as $x\mapsto x^2$.

Comment: Thank you, I mean sequential criterion of uniform continuity.

Comment: In my answer to (**1**), all that I used was the usual definition of uniform continuity.

Comment: Sorry to bother you, but can it be a defination of uniform continuity of $f$ on $D$,  $\text{ for any $\epsilon\gt 0 $ , $\exists \delta \gt 0 $ such that for every pair of sequences $\{u_n\}$,$\{v_n\}$ in $D$ with $|u_{n}-v_{n}|\lt \delta $ $\implies $ $|f(u_n)-f(v_n)|\lt \epsilon $ }$

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/115229/discussion-between-jose-carlos-santos-and-a-learner).